# How to skip failed map tasks in hadoop streaming

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop-streaming

I am running a hadoop streaming mapreduce job which has 26895 map tasks in total. However, one task that deals a certain input always fails. So I set `mapreduce.map.failures.maxpercent=1` and want to skip failed tasks, but the job was still not successful.

```
Kind % Complete  Num Tasks  Pending Running Complete    Killed  Failed/Killed Task Attempts

map     100.00%   26895     0       0       26894       1       8 / 44

reduce  100.00%       1     0       0       0           1       0 / 1
```

How can I do to skip this?

Answer (score 2):

There is a configuration available for the same.
Specify the **mapred.max.map.failures.percent** and **mapred.max.reduce.failures.percent** in the mapred-site.xml to specify the failure threshold. Both are set to 0.

These properties are deprecated now and use following properties for this purpose

```
mapreduce.map.failures.maxpercent
mapreduce.reduce.failures.maxpercent
```

Comment: Why set these two parameters to 0? If I set to 1, does it mean it is ok if 1% of maps or reduces fail? Thanks!

Comment: Those properties are now deprecated in favor of mapreduce.map.failures.maxpercent and mapreduce.reduce. failures.maxpercent